# Can I use conditional operator to pass an input stream to a function?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

There are some cases were I cannot use `if-else` but Only we can use `conditional operator ?` for example in member initialization list e.g:

```
struct vector{
    vector(int n) : sz_{n}, elem{ n ? new int[n] : nullptr }
    {}
};
```

Now I have a template function that takes a reference to `std::istream` or to `std::ifstream` object and a reference to `std::string`. So It is supposed that that function reads input from file `data.txt`; if the input fails then the file stream object failed then pass `std::cin` to read input from standard input device.

```
template<class T>
void readInput(T& in, std::string& str) {
    std::getline(in, str);
}

int main(){

    std::ifstream in("data.txt");
    std::string strLine{};
    readInput<>((in ? in : std::cin), strLine);
    std::cout << strLine << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

- Until this it is OK. But I want to use the function `readInput` to take a `std::getline(T&, std::string)` I mean it takes a pointer to `std::getline`. So this is what I tried:

  ```
  template<class T>
  void readInput(std::istream& (*pfn)(T&, std::string&), T& stream_in, std::string& sLine) {
      (*pfn)(stream_in, sLine);
  }
  ```

As you can see above maybe I am incorrect on how to overload `readInput` to that it takes a pointer to a function like `std::getline()`.

Then I want in main do the same thing as before:

```
readInput<>(std::getline, in ? in : std::cin, strLine);
```

Comment: No need for template, I believe you can just take std::istream& parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the return type of the pointer to function argument returns `T&` not `std::istream`:

```
template<class T>
void readInput(T& (*pfn)(T&, std::string&), T& stream_in, std::string& sLine) {
    (*pfn)(stream_in, sLine);
}
```

And in main you can:

```
readInput<>(std::getline, in ? in : std::cin, strLine);
std::cout << strLine << std::endl;
```